# Paypal express check out specify garment size

Tags: html, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

We are using express checkout for our charity website. Please look at this link: http://bread.org.nz/shop/mens-tee

We want to make it so that the variable size is passed on through the payment. Is this possible? So when we get a notification, we know which size to send.

Answer (score 0):

[PayPal Create-Order](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/orders/#create-order)

Looks like you could add it to the SKU or the Name of the order.
Paypal does not accept many 'Item' variables so you would have to concatenate it to the Name.